# Find all rows that contain a London postcode using SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to find all the orders shipped to London using an SQL query? Simply searching for London in the columns doesn't work as some customers have put the district name rather than "London".

So I thought the best way to go was via the postcode. Would this be the best way to go about finding the rows? And continue with using OR statements for each postcode?

```
select * from tt_order_data 
where ship_postcode like "e1%"
```

According to wiki, this is the postcode range:

> The E, EC, N, NW, SE, SW, W and WC postcode areas (the eight London
> postal districts) comprised the inner area of the London postal region
> and correspond to the London post town.
>
> The BR, CR, DA, EN, HA, IG, SL, TN, KT, RM, SM, TW, UB, WD and CM (the
> 14 outer London postcode areas) comprised the outer area of the London
> postal region.[20]
>
> The inner and outer areas together comprised the London postal
> region.[13]

Comment: What version of MySQL are you working with?

Comment: @esqew Currently using 5.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to leverage [`REGEXP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html) and define a pattern that matches only `ship_postcode`s that begin with one of the aforementioned London postcode character sequences:

```
SELECT *
FROM tt_order_data
WHERE UPPER(TRIM(ship_postcode)) REGEXP '^(E|EC|N|NW|SE|SW|W|WC|BR|CR|DA|EN|HA|IG|SL|TN|KT|RM|SM|TW|UB|WD|CM)'
```

<sup>[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vscutdkSHMKbE9w1nHZQT/2) | [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/s7jvJt/1)</sup>

It's important to keep in mind that you will still need to perform some amount of data cleansing if the inputs weren't properly controlled, as invalid postcodes would match this filter (e.g., `E1 7AA` is valid, but this filter would also consider a string like `ERGO` valid as well).

As an aside, I'm not exactly sure how this will perform with your specific dataset at scale, but if this is for a one-off exercise then it should fit your needs just fine.

Comment: Well the letter bit is always succeeded by a numeric bit, so that should fix that problem